# Best Practice - Session Handling/Timeout

Tags: c++, mysql, session, cookies

What is the best practice to handle Sessions and Timeout in a C++ Server with MySQL.

My C++ Server generates a Session GUID and sends it to the Client-Browser as Set-Cookie.

Should I ever timeout any Session?

Should I save the Session GUID in my MySQL User Table?

When User does something, should I update any Timestamp in a Table or should I save the Sessions and Last Action directly in the C++ Server?

How should I handle "Stay Logged In", never expire the Session GUID? (This could be a big security gap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot help you with the C++ part but here are a few pointers on sessions (server side):

- The Session object should maintain at least

  - the time at which it was last accessed (a request was made)
  - its expiry time that is calculated every time it is accessed by adding the current time to the Max Idle Time (the maximum time during which no access is made before the session is considered expired)
- On every access, the expiry time stored in the Session object is compared to the current time to determine whether the session is expired. If that is the case, the session is invalidated and the Session object removed from the cache of the Session Manager. in the case of a web server, a 302 is sent back to the client and the cookie is expired.
- The Session Manager can implement a session cache which is either in memory or persisted to disk. Persisting it to disk provides session recovery in the case of a server restart. The cache can also ne a distributed cache (Memcache for instance) which allows multiple servers in a cluster to share the Sessions objects and provide load balancing across the servers.

Comment: Sounds good so far, but what would you recommend for "Stay Logged In" or better "Remember Me" handling? Let this Session never expire or maybe after 30 days inactivity?

Comment: There are few ways. One is using a "never" expire cookie with a "permanent" session id. Obviously, if the client changes its credentials of if they expire, the permanent session must be invalidated server side. it is also possible to pas a one time shared secret in the cookie which is use for revalidation of the session.

Comment: What do you exactly mean with a one time shared secret? How would you do that?

Comment: A unique value generated server side, passed to the client (via the cookie) and when redelivered to the server (via the cookie or via  the url parameters) that uniquely identifies and authenticates the client. A session ID is a shared secret. If you implement anything like this be wary of [Session Hijacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking)

Comment: My Session-ID will be a GUID. For more security, I'm going to implement a regeneration of the session id after specific time.. Thank you! :)